# vpn and hotspot client connectivity

Tags: vpn, wireless-router, android

I would like to have vpn connection running on an android device, then using android hotspot, allow a workstation pc to connect to one of the vpn's computer.

So far i managed to establish the vpn connection and connect the workstation to the android hotspot, but unfortunately seems that i can't use the vpn from the workstation.

Do you know if there is some setting i can use to allow that traffic?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: When you say you managed to establish the VPN connection, what did you connect to what exactly? Do you have a VPN software on your android device, the workstation, or both?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I've established the vpn connection using the android integrated vpn software (data is flowing in the 3G line), then the workstation is connected to the android WiFi hotspot

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with my support department at PureVPN and they told me that Android OS has a limitation that it cannot make a VPN hotspot. Sorry :(